# web xml show error in session config tracking mode

Tags: servlets, cookies, web.xml

When I logout from my application or clear cookies to page now redirect to home that a time url to show jsessionId
**../home;jsessionid=E62A8634D411953CB43H01H7B882D7BB**
So I user tracking mode in web.xml **COOKIE**  use this mode to session id not show in URL but web.xml show error icon and I validaet webxml to face **cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'tracking-mode'. No child element is expected at this point.**

My doubt is why this error occurred above tracking mode to how to avoid error in web.xml otherwise any other way is possible?.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using older version of servlet. You need servlet 3 or above.
Please make sure your schema definition is correct

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```